# What is the difference between 'charan' joy and 'makarioi' happiness/blessedness?

Tags: joy

Recently a preacher told us that the *charan* "joy" in James 1:2 isn't happiness.

> My brethren, count it all joy when ye fall into divers temptations; [KJV]

So what **is** the difference between *makarioi* and *charan*, that the former is often translated as happy (or blessed) and the latter translated as joy?

In everyday speech, joy and happiness in English are interchangeable. Or at least, joy just means "particularly enthusiastic happiness" in my experience. So I don't understand the distinction.

In Greek, is there some distinction?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the two words and their meaning from BDAG are these:

**χαρά (chara) = the experience of gladness**, eg, Gal 5:22, John 16:20, 2 Cor 2;3, Heb 12:11, James 4:9, Matt 28:8, Luke 24:52, Acts 15:3, 8:8, Rom 15:13, Phil 2:29, James 1:2, etc.

**μακάριος (makarios)** = (1) **pertaining to being fortunate or happy because of circumstances, *fortunate, happy***, (a) of humans: eg, Acts 26:2, 1 Cor 7:40, Luke 23:29; (b) of transcendent beings viewed as ***privileged, blessed***, 1 Tim 1:11, 6:15.  (2) **pertaining to being especially favored, *blessed, fortunate, happy, privileged***, eg, James 1:25, Luke 6:4, 1 Peter 3:14, 4:14, John 13:17, Matt 11:6, Luke 7:23, 14:15, Rom 4:7, James 1:12, Matt 5:3ff, etc.

Obviously, these two meanings can, at times, overlap.  In order to better understand what the preached meant by "not happy", one would have to ask him.

Incidentally, our English word, "happy" comes from the Old English word "hap" meaning an event that "happened" (from the same root), and thus our word "happy" means fortunate that circumstances just happened that way.

By contrast, "gladness" can often result from one's personal effort at achieving something.  However, as stated above, these two meanings can obviously overlap.